# rviz doesn't show any shape

Tags: rviz, transforms, urdf, tutorial, virtualbox

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I'm trying to build my first URDF model, following this tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch

Booth replicating what's done there, and cloning [this repo](https://github.com/ros/urdf_tutorial) too, I can't see any mash or shape in rviz, only transformations; here's what I see from [chap.4](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch#Material_Girl) code:

[image description http://imageshack.com/a/img924/7439/FGZxFt.jpg](http://imageshack.com/a/img924/7439/FGZxFt.jpg)

There should be cylinders and squares...

Anyone experiencing this issue? I'm running ROS Lunar, Ubuntu 17.04 x64 on VirtualBox (with "3D acceleration" disabled because i don't know why, if it's enabled rviz trows segmentation faults at start)

Side note: [chap.1](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch#One_Shape) I think it's buggy because with no joints there's not any "base_link" transformation supplied by joint_state_publisher, and Rviz go crazy...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271357/rviz-doesn%27t-show-any-shape/) by [Maik993](https://answers.ros.org/users/31992/maik993/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-23**:
We're probably going to have to see what the contents of your URDF is.

**Comment by [Maik993](https://answers.ros.org/users/31992/maik993/) on 2017-09-24**:
I went further and complete the model, the result is an exact copy of [this](https://github.com/ros/urdf_tutorial/tree/master/urdf_tutorial/urdf/05-visual.urdf). In rviz I still don't see any shape, but launching the same file in Gazebo produce a correct visualisation of the entire robot.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-20**:
This could be caused by locale settings. See [ros-visualization/rviz#1151](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/1151#issuecomment-345687074).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is likely a problem with RViz/VirtualBox, and not your URDF.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2017-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Highlighting @gvdhoorn's previous suggestion (for others that come across this issue) that the issue may be related to locales.

Some rviz users have encountered a similar issue on newer ubuntu/debian versions e.g. ROS Lunar on Ubuntu Artful or ROS Melodic on Ubuntu Bionic (see for example: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/1249).

If that's the underlying issue, modifying the following environment variable will fix it:

`export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"`.

---

Originally posted by [dhood](https://answers.ros.org/users/18823/dhood/) with karma: 621 on 2018-07-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PouceHeure](https://answers.ros.org/users/47374/pouceheure/) on 2019-10-17**:
Thanks !! It works, your fix allowed me to use turtlebot3_fake package and display the robot.